# Memory error while doing Hierarchical Clustering

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a large dataset (207989, 23), and I am trying to apply Hierarchical clustering on just one column right now to test if it's suitable for the task at my hand.

What I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing

data = pd.read_csv('gpmd.csv', header = 0)

X = data.loc[:, ['ContextID', 'BacksGas_Flow_sccm']]

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_minmax = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X.values[:,[1]])

import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
dendrogram = sch.dendrogram(sch.linkage(X_minmax, method = 'ward'))
```

after doing this, I am getting the following error:

```
dendrogram = sch.dendrogram(sch.linkage(X_minmax, method = 'ward'))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-429f42b68112>", line 1, in <module>
    dendrogram = sch.dendrogram(sch.linkage(X_minmax, method = 'ward'))

  File "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py", line 708, in linkage
    y = distance.pdist(y, metric)

  File "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py", line 1877, in pdist
    dm = np.empty((m * (m - 1)) // 2, dtype=np.double)

MemoryError
```

Can someone explain what exactly is the problem here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that `sch.linkage` has quadratic memory complexity in terms of the number of original observations. As you have quite a number of them (207989) you should consider trying less memory demanding algorithms.

Comment: Hey, @MikhailBerlinkov .In other words, you mean to say that Hierarchical clustering isn't suitable for large datasets?

Comment: No, I meant only this particular algorithm is quadratic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hierarchical clustering in most variants needs O(n²) memory.

Because of this, most implementations will fail at around 65535 instances, when they hit the 32 bit mark (some may fail at 32k already). But just do the math: n * n * 8 bytes for double precision: how much memory would you need?